# Flatten folded line JTS

Tags: jts-topology-suite

In my data I have many occurrences of 2 lines that follow the same path, but in opposing directions. Applying `LineMerger` to this data results in the lines being joined together, but not merged into each other.

e.g. Given two lines with the same nodes

```
--->--->--->---

---<---<---<---
```

I want either:

```
--->--->--->---
```

or

```
---<---<---<---
```

But instead I get

```
--->--->--->--+
              |
---<---<---<--+
```

or

```
+-->--->--->---
|
+--<---<---<---
```

Is there a way to obtain my desired result in JTS?

Comment: OpenJUMP has a quality assurance tool "Delete duplicate geometries" so it is certainly possible.

Comment: I have detected it manually prior to linemerging. I'm hoping for a JTS-centric method.

Comment: The tool pretty sure implements a JTS-centric method and code is somewhere in https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/core/trunk/src/. You can also write an question to jump-pilot mailing list  https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/mailman/jump-pilot-devel/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you union the lines using [Geometry.union](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#union--) ?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think I recall that union was a no-op, as the lines are not equivalent when reversed.

Comment: As long as the lines do have identical vertices (in opposite order) then Geometry.union will work.  It will return a MultiLineString, which can then be merged to provide a single line.

Comment: I see. I probably stopped exploring this option when I got the multilinestring.